# how to map # to , (when , is my leader) while using vim-sneak

Tags: key-bindings, leader

I use ',' as leader, so when I f/t and I want to go to previous hit, I cannto use ','

I tried using #:

```
nnoremap # ,
```

My mapping shows up (I think), :map # shows this

```
n #      * ,
```

but it does nothing. Something obvious I am missing?

thanks

Comment: This should work just fine. Can you check that you can see the mapping with `:map #` (to query it?) Do you really have a next occurrence of the character you're searching in the same line, that `,` would normally find?

Comment: added info, thanks! But while I was looking into this I realized what is most probably the issue. I am using vim-sneak, that takes over f with 'nmap f <Plug>Sneak_f'. I am pretty sure this has something to do..I should ask them maybe

Comment: Please edit the question to mention vim-sneak...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned vim-sneak in your comments, and that's probably it here.

vim-sneak will try to map `,`. It actually expects you might be using `,` as a leader/localleader, it will check for whether you've mapped it and, if so, it will check for whether you've mapped `\` to `,` and use that instead. You can see the code doing that [here](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/blob/1.8.1/plugin/sneak.vim#L357).

Since you want to use `#` instead, just map it directly to the `<Plug>` mapping exposed by vim-plug:

```
nmap # <Plug>Sneak_,
omap # <Plug>Sneak_,
xmap # <Plug>Sneak_,
```

It should be fine to add this to your vimrc (even though the plug-in actually gets loaded later on), but if you run into issues with that, consider creating a file named `~/.vim/after/plugin/*.vim` and add those commands there instead, that will run after vim-sneak is loaded.

You could also use that file to remove any vim-sneak mappings from `,` (if it happens to be adding any), if you intend to use it as a leader.